# Recognition of changed data in a multi user database

Tags: c#, database, hash, multi-user

I've got a database which will be accessed by multiple users. 
For example `User 1` retrieves a list of all available datasets in the table `"Test"`. `User 2` does the same thing and both users afterwards got the same datasets.

So now, if `User 1` wants to write `ABC` to dataset with `Index 1`, he can do so and the dataset is persistent.
But if `User 2` NOW wants to write `ABB` to dataset with `Index 1`, how can he know, that the dataset has already been updated?

Is there a pattern for multi user database access or can I just use hashing algorithms to obtain if there is an updated dataset?

Or are there any other approaches?

Comment: keyword is optimistic locking.. "Solution number 2:- Use timestamp data type" is good..  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/6-ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt

Comment: Assuming your application is asynchronus and you are retrieving data, looking at it, and then making changes, you need to handle your check for data changing in the same sql operation as  your write to the DB, so you *can* "use hashing algorithms to obtain if there is an updated ataset" but if you do that and then go back to write you're still open to contention

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible answers here and a lot depends on your application architecture.

Are two users going to be working on the same row at the same time? And if so, if they have different ideas about what data should be there, this sounds like a business problem that needs to be considered and resolved.

That said, if you have a front end that is receiving data and then trying to write back, using either a time stamp or a checksum as part of validation is a common and useful way of handling this solution.

If I were implementing this I would use a stored procedure and force my application to pass the checksum back to the proc. The procedure would check to see if the checksum is still accurate and the write would fail if it wasn't.